# Hide ?nocache query string but show it's effects

Tags: php, url, caching, url-rewriting

I'm in a position where my site absolutely doesn't like cache. somehow caching is causing a huge issue and my CMS doesn't allow me to exclude certain scripts from cache so I can load the page smoothly. So what I did is to create a redirect from my URL yourdomain.com to yourdomain.com/?nocache. This will forcefully show the user a non-cached site. This completely works for me.

However, I want to hide the "?nocache" part from the URL and STILL forcefully show the non cached version of the site. Any help on this please?

I'm on wordpress BTW on wodpress.com where they said cache cannot be disabled and even cache plugins have no effect so I can't exclude certain scripts from cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've realized that the best way to do this is not by the nocache redirect but to actually pass nocache headers in the theme header.

I did it by passing

```
nocache_headers();
```

More at: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/nocache_headers/

in the header.php file and that has solved my issue. Now the site loads without cache successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Use JS to append `?nocache` (or better yet `?timestamp`, where `timestamp` is the current Unix time, e.g. `1598155107`) to the end of every linked URL (or `&timestamp` if the URL already contains a query string).

This solution uses jQuery but you could adapt it to vanilla JS:

```
$('a').each(function(i,link){
    let ts = new Date().getTime(); // E.g. 1598155107
    let href = $(this).attr('href');
    if ( href.match(/\?/) ) {
        href += '&';
    } else {
        href += '?';
    }
    href += ts;
    $(this).attr('href', href);
});
```